# What is an automated option for using x86 npm packages on arm?

Tags: npm, x86

Any time I run `npm install` on an ARM machine (ubuntu) I am rolling a dice and sometimes they do not have arm binary and the code does not compile, so I have to replace the package or go spelunking on why it did not compile...

Is there a way to use x86 packages on ARM machine without individual configuration?

Ideal way would be if the package manager could not find an ARM build and compilation failed it would just use an emulator to run x86 binary.

Comment: Do you want to run the whole node.js as an x86 executable in an emulator like qemu-user?  That would likely come at a significant performance penalty.  (Emulating just for specific x86 libraries with the main program running as ARM would take special support which I assume doesn't exist, since it would be tricky to get right.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I was hoping maybe there was something ad hoc solution already out here considering ARM MacBook's are a thing.
Would running npm in x86 fix things? I am not sure if npm is used in runtime or just for orchestration. However, it does I can eat the performance hit.

Comment: Isn't `npm` just a package manager for node.js?  Running x86 `npm` would let you install x86 binaries, but an ARM `node` couldn't use them.